# OpenCV - background removal and object detection

Tags: opencv

I need to detect where objects (mostly people) are in relation to a wall. I can have a fixed position camera in the ceiling so I thought to get an image of the space with nothing in it. Then use the difference of that and the current camera image to get an image with just the things. Then I can do blob detection I think to get the positions (only need x).
Does this seem sound? I'm not very accomplished in OpenCV so am looking for some advice.

Answer (score -1):

That would be one way of going about it, but not very robust as the video feed won't produce consistent precise images so the background will never be nicely subtracted out, and people walking through the scene will occlude light and could also possibly match parts of your background.

This process of removing the background from a video is simply dubbed "background subtraction" and there are [built-in OpenCV methods for it](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractor).

OpenCV has tutorials on their site showing the basics, for both [python](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html) and [C++](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not posisitve background subtraction is really what I need. It seems a bit complicated especially with live video. Have thought of using a depth buffer like that on a Kinect. With a straight down view it would seem the people should stand out fairly well.
I'll do some more reading on bg subtraction though - it may still be what I end up using.

Comment: The Gaussian mixture model is pretty much the standard for background subtraction in video feed. You can see the seminal paper [here](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/publications/avbs01/avbs01.pdf). If you have a way to get depth maps, then sure, that could work too. The tutorials aren't that complex though the code is a little long. OpenCV as usual does all the hard work for you :)